# Find a random variable using a relation and given sufficient inputs in Javascript

Tags: javascript, math

Lets say I have a relation `E = mgh`. And I have four textboxes on my site. Given three values, I can compute the value of the fourth variable by rearranging the variables by hand. But how to do so programmatically, efficiently, without redundant code.
Now the worst way of doing (which I have painfully done in the past in a [different language](https://github.com/mrtechtroid/techycalc/blob/master/Version%201.0/)) is manually checking which of the four variables is not inputted in the textboxes and then use a precomputed relation like `g = E/mh` to get its value. But this is bad because as the formula becomes more and more complex with more variable or different powers, it is tiresome and impractical to do by hand.

So what I'm looking for, is a Proof of Concept for JavaScript which can take a certain no of values, and a relation relating those values to find out the value of the missing variable on its own. Also note: the relation may not be a simple relation it might be complex like `E=(m^1/2)(g^1/3)(h^4)`

An Example of this might be [this site](https://www.omnicalculator.com/math/percentage) where I can plug in some values and it will auto-compute the missing value on its own. I don't know what underlying structure they might be using, as they might have all the relations precomputed by hand.

**EDIT**
For all those out there, who feel this question being like asking for a Library recommendation, it is not. I'm looking for a minimal example which can do the following:

1. Using Array's/ Objects transform a given relation into another. (Generally referred in mathematical terms as rearranging the terms)
2. Now Using the above relation compute without using `eval()`
   I know what to do for the second, i.e take the new expression, find the variable and then put the value at the place of the variable in the string.
   Then evaluate the expression. Like (`"y=x+3*e"`) -> (`y="3+3*30"`)
   How do I make the first step possible?
   (OR) Do you have a better approach for this problem.

Comment: To make this task simple and generic, you'll definitely need a library, but asking library recommendations is off-topic at SO.

Comment: @Teemu I didn't explicitly ask for a library. I'm asking for a minimal example on how I can approach it. Like how to do the variable restructuring/rewriting programmatically. And i'm pretty sure there isn't a well known library at the moment which achieves the above task. So when I asked for a library I was hoping to find a obscure code snippet/ open source program by some other user on Github or something which already automates the above task.

Comment: Yes, I know you didn't explicitly ask for a library (though someone has already voted to close the question because of that). The biggest job is to make a math parser, which can recognize all the roles and values of the terms and operators in an equation, then reduce the terms by calculating all the number values, after that it should be relatively easy to implement those few generic rules for equation resolving. Any of these can't be represented  "just in a minimal example". A quick search brought up [this](https://nerdamer.com/) library, most likely you can find more.